# Top War Statue/Building Cleanup

Tags: top-war

I've recently just came back to playing Top War (I took a break) and my base is a mess because I didn't organize it the last time I played. I want to move all the statues (Megatron Statue, Cedar, Battlement, etc.) I noticed it's very hard to move these statues and/or place them into storage. This is very time-consuming, so I wonder if there's a way to put all of the statues into storage so I can just place them down.